# E: py3compile:243: Requested versions are not installed

Tags: package-management, dpkg, python3

Am trying to run the command `sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev -y`. But for most `apt-get update` command I end up getting below error. Not sure what is wrong with python package here

```
E: py3compile:243: Requested versions are not installed
dpkg: error processing package python3-apt (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-minimal
 python3-apt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

System info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Python versions :

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.4
```

```
$ apt-cache policy python3-minimal
python3-minimal:
  Installed: 3.5.1-3
  Candidate: 3.5.1-3
  Version table:
 *** 3.5.1-3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

```
& type -a python3
python3 is /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python3
python3 is /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python3
python3 is /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python3
python3 is /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python3
python3 is /usr/bin/python3
```

```
$ file /usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3: symbolic link to /usr/bin/python3.7
```

```
$ echo $PATH
/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/rxy/bin:/home/rxy/.local/bin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/rxy/bin:/home/rxy/.local/bin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/rxy/bin:/home/rxy/.local/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/rxy/bin:/home/rxy/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

```
file /usr/bin/python3.5
/usr/bin/python3.5: cannot open `/usr/bin/python3.5' (No such file or directory)
```

Contents of `~/.profile`:

```bash
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
# include .bashrc if it exists
if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
. "$HOME/.bashrc"
fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH='/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin':"$PATH"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112736/discussion-between-kulfy-and-rk3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

py3compile file is provided by python3-minimal whose default version on Xenial Xerus is 3.5.1-3 and according to [Ubuntu Package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python3-minimal), it depends on `python3.5-minimal` but you have python3.7-minimal installed and default python3 set to python3.7 which is a very bad idea. Python is an integral part of Linux system and default Python shouldn't be touched unless you're experimenting things and in mood of corrupting system.

You need to restore default Python 3, which 3.5 for you, by installing `python3.5 minimal` package and changing symbolic links. To do that, run:

```
sudo apt install python3.5-minimal
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```

Also, the order in which paths are given in `PATH` variable also defines priority. You may consider moving custom path to the end by modifying `~/.profile` and changing

```
export PATH='/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin':"$PATH"
```

to

```
export PATH="$PATH":'/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin'
```

Logout and relogin to make changes take place. Run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and retry the installation of packages mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I have been hitting my head for quite some time and have come up with this solution (not nice, but if it works):

Based on the thought that Python is, in essence, an interpreted language, `py3compile` might be nice but should not be needed, so:

```
mv /usr/bin/py3compile /usr/bin/py3compile.orig
ln -s $(which true) /usr/bin/py3compile
```